# Python 3.6: NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to Python (3.6). My console is giving me the following error: "NameError: name 'A' is not defined". How can I fix this error?

```
def NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z):
  a_V=15.67
  a_S=17.23
  a_C=0.75
  a_A=93.2
  a_P=0

  if A%2==1:
    a_P=0
  else:
    if Z%2==0:
      a_P=12.0
    else:
      a_P=-12.0

  B = (a_V)*A - ((a_S)*(A**(2/3))) - (a_C)*(Z**2/(A**(1/3))) - ((a_A)*(((A-(2*Z))**2)/A)) + ((a_P)/A**(1/2))

  return B

def NuclearBindingEnergyPerNucleon(A,Z):
    return NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z)/A

print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z))
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z)/A)
```

Comment: What are A and Z in your print statements at the bottom?

Comment: You should define A and Z in the end two lines because you used them without defining them outside thier function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare A and Z variables values for example as following

```
A =12
Z = 5
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z))
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z)/A)
```

it will output

```
55.008666416854204
4.584055534737851
```

Comment: I had left out some code and spotted it - thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When you use parameters in a function you dont need to define them because they must be defined when the function used, but when you use some function and you want to take some values inside them as a parameter so you must defined them before using in the functions parameter so in your example you just can define A and Z like :-

```
...
A = 20
Z = 30

print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z))
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(A,Z)/A)
...
```

And also you can use numbers instead them like:-

```
...
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(70, 60))
print(NuclearBindingEnergy(80,90)/100)
...
```